# How to create one to many records in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, unpivot

I have a table that I am trying to populate multiple values based on Did.

Original table:

| Sid | Did | Time1s | Time1e | Time2s | Time2e | Time3s | Time3e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | 1 | 8:00 | 8:30 | 8:40 | 9:20 | 10:00 | 10:30 |
| U2 | 2 | 9:00 | 9:30 | 10:00 | 10:30 | 11:00 | 11:30 |

And I would need like the below

Output :

| Sid | Did | Time1s | Time1e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U1 | 1 | 8:00 | 8:30 |
| U1 | 1 | 8:40 | 9:20 |
| U1 | 1 | 10:00 | 10:30 |
| U2 | 2 | 9:00 | 9:30 |
| U2 | 2 | 10:00 | 10:30 |
| U2 | 2 | 11:00 | 11:30 |

How would I do this in postgres? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73318871/13808319

Comment: I reviewed the link, but being a fresher to Postgres,I could not understand it completely. Still trying. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this approach

```
SELECT t.sid,
       CASE v.i WHEN 1 THEN "Time1s"
                WHEN 2 THEN "Time2s"
                WHEN 3 THEN "Time3s"
           END AS Time1s,
       ...
FROM your_table t
     CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) v(i)
```